# How can I set length of array to field value in the same class?

Tags: java, arrays, field

I made the the field value maxSeats as to represent the number of max seat that will be in the main class like this.
Main Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student a = new Student("Abigail", 1, 5);
    Student b = new Student("Benny", 1, 6);
    Student c = new Student("Charles", 1, 10);
    Student d = new Student("Denise", 2, 12);
    Student e = new Student("Eleanor", 2, 9);
    Student f = new Student("Fred", 2, 5); 

    SchoolBus sb1 = new SchoolBus(3, 1);
    SchoolBus sb2 = new SchoolBus(3, 2);
    sb1.getRemainSeat();
    sb1.addStudent("Benny", 1, 6);
}
```

Other class:

```
private int maxSeats;
private int routeNum;
String[] studentArray = new String[3];
public SchoolBus(int mS, int rN){
    mS = maxSeats;
    rN = routeNum;
}
```

And I want the field studentArray to have the length of the maxSeats, but it seems that this sets the length of array to 0, and I get outofboudary error.  Is there any way to properly set the length of array to the field value in the same class?

Comment: Did you mean to do `maxSeats = mS;` and `routeNum = rN;`?

Answer (score 5):

1) You need to create your array after you define the value of the variable `maxSeats`.

2) You're setting the values in your constructor backwards.

Try this:

```
private int maxSeats;
private int routeNum;
String[] studentArray;
public SchoolBus(int mS, int rN){
    maxSeats = mS;
    routeNum = rN;
    studentArray = new String[maxSeats]; //Define an array of length [maxSeats]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
String[] studentArray ;
public SchoolBus(int mS, int rN){ 
   mS = maxSeats;// this it the wrong way around
   maxSeats= mS; // this ist the way to go!
   rN = routeNum;
   studentArray = new String[mS];
}
```